# Spring - Multiple datasource programmatically

Tags: spring, datasource

In my application i have to create multiple datasource (i don't know how many).. this come from a configuration file where i setup each one of them (suppose that all of this are Oracle datasource).

How i can handle this and select one based on another parameter in configuration file ?

My idea was to place all this datasource in a `Map` and with the key i can get the correct DataSource.

The problem is that all of them should be created with `@Bean` annotation, and i can access anywhere in the application.

Do you have some suggestion ?

**EDIT**:
From configuration file i can have:

```
database1.username=...
database1.password=...

database2.username=...
database2.password=...
```

When application start read this configuration file and should create separate `@Bean` for each one, so i can select later the right DataSource based on other configuration parameters.

Comment: @Bean for each DataSource, with unique names.  You don't need a Map; use the BeanFactory.  Ask it to give you the DataSource by name.  Why duplicate?

Comment: Look my edit. I dont know how many DataSource i can have, user will define DataSource in a configuration file and i have to create them. So, i cant' use @Bean definition. I cant use bean in XML too because user can't know anything about Spring, him just write properties in file :)

Answer (score 0):

Spring Environment [Profiles](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-31-environment-profiles) should be the solution to your problem.
For example, you could set up your application using the configuration file in order to make use of only those data-sources named "group_a".